# Use mkvtoolnix / mkvmerge to merge audio track with title

Tags: audio, video, language, matroska

I want to merge a .mkv video with a German audio track with an matching external English audio track.

When I use the basic commmand

`mkvmerge -o output-with-two-tracks.mkv input-video-with-german-track.mkv english-track.dts`

The German track keeps its name 'DTS 5.1 @ 1510 kbps - [Deutsch]' the English track is named 'Title 2'. How do I rename the English track when merging it?

I've tried the `--language 1:ger --language 2:eng` option and the `--track-name 2:English` but most certainly I did it wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trial and error for the win. I had the order of the ids and file names mixed up.

```
mkvmerge -o output-with-two-tracks.mkv --language 0:ger input-video-with-german-track.mkv --language 0:eng --track-name "0:DTS 5.1 @ 1510 kbps" english-track.dts
```

…leads to the desired result. Both tracks named DTS 5.1 @ 1510 kbps + the language.